# How to automatically set height of UITableView based on cells that are inside of it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView in the middle of a screen and want to adjust the height of the tableview based on the amount of cells that are in it, where the data is being fetched from an API. In other words, make the height of the tableview `x * height of each cell`.

I've looked around and saw that you can adjust the cell height automatically based on what's in them, but this isn't what I'm looking for (they're all gonna be the same size).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use just only `UITableView`?
You can achieve it by using `UIStackView`. If you need to add scroll behavior - that is also possible, google stack view + scroll.

Below a dynamic height table view custom class.

```swift
class DynamicHeightTableView: UITableView {

    // By default UITableView doesn't have `intrinsicContentSize`
    // Overriden in order to make it work with autolayout system
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()

        return contentSize
    }

    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()

        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

1. Declare a variable inside your `UIViewController` subclass like this.

```swift
private var contentSizeObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

2. Inside `viewDidLoad()` or whenever your `myTableView` is set up, start observing contentSize changes.

```swift
contentSizeObservation = myTableView.observe(\.contentSize, options: .new, changeHandler: { [weak self] (tv, _) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.myTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tv.contentSize.height
})
```

3. Do NOT Forget to clean this up in `deinit` call -

```swift
deinit {
    contentSizeObservation?.invalidate()
}
```

This approach will make sure that your `myTableView` is always as big in height as it's content.